# How to use multiple dimension array in input in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I have a query.use array with an input box.

```
<input type="text" name="['pnr'][a_o1]" />
```

How to use multiple dimension array in input in PHP. I want to use an array in name of input in PHP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: <input type="text" name="['first']['2nd']"  />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="input[pnr][pnr1]" />
<input type="text" name="input[pnr][pnr2]" />
<input type="text" name="input[pnr][pnr3]" />
```

In your php script, do this:

```
print_r($_POST['input'][0]);#returns all input associated with that array
```

This approach is cleaner as it reduces the number of parameters you pass to your controller function.

Comment: <input type="text" name="input[pnr][pnr]" />
<input type="text" name="input[pnr][pnr2]" />
<input type="text" name="input[pnr][pnr3]" /> in php